# unexpected value in my feet to meters converter with pure javascript

Tags: javascript

//I'm trying to get a result in meters out of an input in feet.

```
            <div id="inner-wrapper">
                <label for="feet-input">Enter feet
                </label>
                <input type="number" id="feet-input" placeholder="Feet">

                <label for="result">Result
                </label>
                <div id="result"></div>

                <button id="calculate" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
                <button id="clear" onclick="clear()">Clear</button> 
            </div>
```

//For any number I type I get 0 as answer.

```
        var feetInput = document.getElementById("feet-input").value;
        var result = document.getElementById("result");    
        var total;

        function calculate(){
            total = feetInput * 0.3048;
            result.innerHTML = total;
            return total;


        }

            function clear(){
                feetInput.value = "";
                result.value = ""; 

            }



    //For any number I type get 0 as result.
```

For any number I type get 0 as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because your  `var feetInput = document.getElementById("feet-input").value;` is only executed once you need to fetch always latest value on function call as below

```js
 //var feetInput = document.getElementById("feet-input").value;//only executed once
        var result = document.getElementById("result");    
        var total;

        function calculate(){
        var feetInput = document.getElementById("feet-input").value;
            total = feetInput * 0.3048;
            result.innerHTML = total;
            return total;


        }

            function clear(){
                feetInput.value = "";
                result.value = ""; 

            }



    //For any number I type get 0 as result.
```

```html
<div id="inner-wrapper">
                <label for="feet-input">Enter feet
                </label>
                <input type="number" id="feet-input" placeholder="Feet">

                <label for="result">Result
                </label>
                <div id="result"></div>

                <button id="calculate" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
                <button id="clear" onclick="clear()">Clear</button> 
            </div>
```

Comment: I thought that by declaring the "var feetInput" outside the function makes it accessible when i use it from within the calculate() function.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue that you have is that the value from `feet-input` is ONLY read when the page is loaded. 
You'll need to get the value of `feet-input` before you do the calculation.

Just add `var feetInput = document.getElementById("feet-input").value;` to the line immediately after `function calculate(){`

Codepen: https://codepen.io/DeathCamel57/pen/xPPGrp?editors=0010